# Does a mix of cocktail sauce and tartare sauce have a special name?

Tags: sauce, condiments

What does one get when one combines cocktail sauce and tartar sauce in equal parts?

Comment: Russell, welcome to Seasoned Advice! The part whether the combination of the two sauces has e.g. a special name is something that the community can answer (although I suspect not). Whether this would make a good seafood dip is opinion-based, which we don’t do here. I suggest you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works. For now, I’m removing the opinion-based part.

Comment: It's called Tartail sauce, or Cocktar sauce, whichever you like best ;) . The second one sounds like something out of the Klingon dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Barring the thickening with finely sieved hard-boiled egg/egg-yolk, this combination is heading in the direction of [Thousand Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Island_dressing) dressing. Given that recipe is so variable, you could just about get away with calling it that.